# Dynamic Query error

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

When I try to execute below query im getting error at 4th line like "
ORA-06512: at line 5", where "sample" is dynamic global temporary table.

```
 declare max_seq_dp varchar2(20);
 cnt number(20);
 begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) into cnt from sample';
  dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
  if (cnt)>0 then
     begin
       select max(sequence_number) into max_seq_dp 
       from sample1 where column1 = '2045'
       and is_active = 1;
       dbms_output.put_line(max_seq_dp);
     end;
  end if;
 end;
```

Thanks

Comment: change this if (cnt)>0 then to       if cnt >0 then

Answer (score 4):

The variable needs to be specified outside the execute immediate:

`execute immediate 'select count(*) from sample' into cnt;`

But as long as the table name is not dynamic, you can do the same thing *without* execute immediate:

```
begin
   select count(*) into cnt from sample;
   ...
```